# running the react native application synchronously with the server

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, express

I have created a server for sql database with express js in my react native application. When i start the server and run my application there is no problem. It works successfully. However, i want the server to be triggered and started when the application runs. Anyone have a suggestion for this?

Comment: You want to set up your test backend to run when your app runs?  You can add scripts to your package.json that do this, but they would depend on your directory structure.

Comment: I have the same problem when I add dev command to package.json, I need to run the server separately

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your goal.  Can you update your question with a very specific idea of what you want to happen?

Comment: I want to run the application synchronously with the local mssql server